# Error in launching AVD - The filesystem is already 140800 (4k) blocks long - Nothing to do

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I got the error `resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 140800 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!` when I try to run the AVD.

I'm using a Mac and I've done all the necessary updates to the SDK Manager.

Does anyone know what might be?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the details of your AVD? any special configuration there? specifically , any configuration that has to do with volume size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug has been assigned and might be in the next release: (Although for Ubuntu, base might be the same)

[Issue 189030:  Emulator claims it doesn't launch in Ubuntu (but it does!)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189030)

And maybe related info here

[Issue 196283:  Emulator boot is flaky - Could not bind or listen to socket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196283)

Comment: Ah. Fixed that. Thanks.